# Unity player and floor 2D objects not colliding

Tags: game-physics, game-development

I am not very experienced in game development so bear with me. I am trying to build a 2d game in `Unity`, and I just added a floor tile, but it doesn't work. I've tried adding a `Rigidbody2d`, I've turned `isTrigger` on and off for both colliders multiple times, etc. nothing I do works. I have attached two images of the inspector for the character and floor.
Any help is appreciated. :]

[character inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qiZG.png)

[ground inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9Vmz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your character to stay on top the floor you should disable `IsTriggered` option in your `colliders`. There is no need to add a `RigidBody2D` to your floor object. Only one of them should have it, in your situation your player.